# How do Medics gain points on Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

I'd like to play as a Medic on Team Fortress 2, but I could not find anywhere on the official wiki how they can earn points.

I know that if you use the secondary weapon and kill someone with it (of course) you gain points, but if you are using the primary weapon that only heal and UberCharge friends how do I gain points? Are there Medic-specific ways to earn points?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Points#Points) on the official TF2 wiki, Medics can earn points by:

- Healing (1 point for every 600 health healed)
- Deploying UberCharge (1 point per charge deployed)

This is in addition to the standard ways of earning points for all classes:

- 1 point for every kill
- 0.5 points for every kill assist (as a Medic, healing the killer at the time of the kill will usually count as an assist. See [this page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kill_assist) for more detail)
- 2 points for capturing a control point (on CP maps) or the Intelligence (on CTF maps)
- 2 points for pushing the cart for 10 seconds (on Payload maps)
- 1 extra point for defence kills
- 1 point for destroying enemy buildings
- 1 extra point for revenge kills
- 2 extra points for killing a Medic who has a full UberCharge

Answer (score 2):

A medic's primary source of points is [Kill Assists](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kill_assist#Priority). There are points given for deploying Ubercharge and for healing, but as per that link, every time a player gets a kill, was being healed by a Medic at the time, and the target wasn't under the effects of jarate, the medic doing the healing gets an assist. If two medics were healing at the same time, the first to have started gets the assist.

Since each assist is worth half a point, something as simple and common as Ubering a Heavy who subsequently rips through the enemy can be worth quite a bit to a Medic's score.